# Reorder cells in UICollectionView + NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uicollectionview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a UICollectionView which displays entities from CoreData with NSFetchedResultsController. As you can see on the screenshot, the user can select multiple cells which get marked with a border.

[image: Screenshot]

My model has basically just a string and a boolean for handling selection via the UICollectionView.

```
var url: String
var selected: Bool
var section:Section
```

I have implemented `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)` in order to support reordering of the `UICollectionViewCells`. The drag and drop operation works fine, but I am struggling with saving the moved items to CoreData. Do I have to add a `position` property to my model?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    var sourceArray = self.fetchedResultController.fetchedObjects
    let item = sourceArray?.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.item)
    sourceArray?.insert(item!, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    coreData.saveContext()
}
```

I tried to modify `fetchedResultsController.fechtedObjects` directly, which is not wokring since this property is read-only. What's the best way to do drag&drop with `UICollectionView` and `NSFetchedResultsController`.

EDIT:

Initial sorting of the `UICollectionView` is based on an index property in the `Section` model. Currently there is just this sorting key for the sections, nothing for items within the sections.

```
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "section.index", ascending: false)]
let resultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath:"section.name", cacheName: nil)
```

Comment: How are you sorting the items to display them in the collection view?

Comment: I have updated the question. Sorting of the sections is based on a property of the section model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've found, you can't just tell `NSFetchedResultsController` to change the order of objects in its `fetchedObjects` array. That array is sorted based on your sort descriptor, and is read-only.

So you have two possible options:

1. Change the property you're using in the sort descriptor, so that the new sort result will match the result of the drag and drop operation. Save changes, and `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate methods will fire. You've changed the order and your fetched results controller will reflect that in its `fetchedObjects` array.
2. Don't use `NSFetchedResultsController`, just do a fetch and save the results in your own array. Re-order the items in your own array but don't change anything that Core Data cares about.